# Display First Column with fill_parent width the first row of Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have a Screen that will be displayed with list of Items in GridView. I have designed as per my requirement which shows 2 columns and n number of rows.

Till Here it is ok but now there is a new requirement in which I need to show first column with Big Preview.

---

### First Item stays here

### seconditem|thirditem

### fourthitem|fifthitem

### Again sixthItem stays full

continues....

Is this possible in Android GridView? 
Can someone help how to achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to do a "pull to refresh" list? I'm too. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible in `GridView`,as it does not support spanning,i think `TableLayout` fits better your case,as it supports row span.Hope that clears it out

Comment: If I use TableLayout then I will lose all functionalities. because i can't set adapter, onitemclicklisteners.